crear mail para enviar un string de mysql
Buen dia a todos.
estoy con un desarrollo y estoy creo ya emepzandole a meterme a esto del Visual basic.
Tengo que enviar un mail desde un formulario el cual debe entregar 2 string  ya sea para aceptar o rechazar
string 1: "UPDATE rh_vacaciones_en_uso Set periodocumplido = 'no' WHERE folio_empleado = '193245'"
string 2: "UPDATE rh_vacaciones_en_uso Set periodocumplido = 'si' WHERE folio_empleado = '193245'"
el envio que hace el formulario hasta hoy es algo sencillo ya que es con este codigo.
Try
    EmailMessage.From = New MailAddress("correodestinatario@midominio.com")
    EmailMessage.To.Add("mail_origen@modominio.com")
    EmailMessage.Subject = "Nuevo Folio de prueba 123456"
    EmailMessage.Body = "Se ha generado el Folio 123 y ha sido enviado a Mesa de Control" 
    EmailMessage.IsBodyHtml = True
    Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
    SMTP.Port = 587
    SMTP.EnableSsl = True
    SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("correo@midominio.com", "iwvtemnhcvfaaryo")
    SMTP.Send(EmailMessage)
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try

mi pregunta es si se puede colocar un link que mande directo el string al servidor
mi conexion al mysql es asi:
Public var2_Conexion_a_base As New MySqlConnection("data source=192.168.1.100;port=3306;user id=admin_server_1; password=Matrix;database=base0101")

Gracias por su apoyo

Acabas de publicar un ip, usuario y password reales de una base real?? si es asi, ya debes cambiar esa informacion porque ya fue publica... De paso, no entiendo tu problema...
